# WARNING: Could not find packages folder or virtual environment. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxxx' in Azure App Services

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, passlib

I have the following error in a Python application deployed to linux in Azure App Services.

```
2019-03-27T21:19:19.356340459Z WARNING: Could not find packages folder or virtual environment.
2019-03-27T21:19:19.356340459Z   File "/home/site/wwwroot/application.py", line 3, in 
2019-03-27T21:19:19.356344259Z     from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
2019-03-27T21:19:19.356347559Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'passlib'
```

Its the same if I use pandas so doesn't seem to be related to the library.

Although I have added the file to my requirements.txt its not run as part of the installation.

```
Flask==1.0.2
passlib==1.7.1
functools==3.3.0
```

The environment is Linux on Azure App Services. These are the steps I followed,

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux

I have tried connecting to the environment using the Kudo BASH, but when checking the python version its 2.7 not 3.7 per the deployment. I'm wondering if im in the host os and not the docker container the site is hosted in. (Bug/Issue?). I can find the deployment under /home/site/wwwroot and i have tried using pip to install the requirement.txt. Since it isnt the version of pyton running on the site I assume that's why its failing. It will collect the libaries but not proceed any further.

I am unable to SSH, this seems to be down, it is never able to connect to the site.

I have tried the development and production plans.

I dont want to deploy my own docker as the goal is to have MS Manage the patching of the whole environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually functools==3.7 causing all installs to fail. Seems to be unavailable as a package, yet is included anyway as Wraps work without it.

I was able to find the deployment logs under logs/kudu/deployment which lead to this discovery.